# an static function used in StringHashTable thread-safe?

Tags: c++, hash, static, thread-safety

I have got an  StringHashTable class from
http://preshing.com/20110603/hash-table-performance-tests/

The following  are parts of source :

```
class StringHashTable
{
    static uint fnv1Hash(const char *key)
    {
        unsigned int hash = 2166136261ul;
        for (const char *s = key; *s; s++)
            hash = (16777619 * hash) ^ (*s);
        return hash;
    };

    uint &operator[](const char *key)
    {
        uint hash = fnv1Hash(key) & (m_tableSize - 1);
        Bucket *firstBucket = m_table + hash;
        Bucket *b = firstBucket;
        if (b->key)
        {
            do
            {
                if (strcmp(b->key, key) == 0)
                    return b->value;// Found existing bucket
                b = b->next;
            } while (b);
        }
        ..........
    }
}
```

Suppose that  I have the  global var :

```
StringHashTable hashtable(1024) ; //m_tableSize now 1024
```

And then the following is in main :

```
hashtable["0000"] = 0 ;
....
hashtable["9999"] = 9999 ;
```

After fill in all the data I need , thread 1 to n  will get value according to key

```
while(1)
{
    s = get(); //return string like "0000" ... "9999"
    echo << hashtable[s.c_str()] << endl ;
}
```

I wonder if the StringHashTable would work fine in thread at first , 
because the function fnv1Hash is static , on second thought , there is no 
static  member data in this StringHashTable  ,  so  while thread1 is doing 
hashtable["0000"]  and thread2 is doing  hashtable["9999"] at the very same time
both thread1 are calling  fnv1Hash they will both get the right hash returned !!!

My question is : different thread call static uint fnv1Hash(const char *key) with 
different key at the very same time still work fine ?  In   StringHashTable , fnv1Hash
is static  for any reason ?!

Comment: In your scenario, the data is only ever read concurrently, never modified. I don't see any thread safety concerns. `fnv1Hash` in particular doesn't access any shared data at all. In any case, `static` keyword has nothing to do with threads - it's not clear why you are so hung up on it.

Comment: It is thread safe as long as the input (i.e. `key`) is local variable at the caller, means not global nor static. local variables are located in the stack, and each thread has stack of its own.

Comment: @SHR: just because data is on the stack doesn't necessarily mean it is thread-safe, though: although it is a Bad Idea, a thread go send pointers to its stack to another thread.

Comment: @DietmarKühl that's why I wrote "local at the caller". maybe I should have write "local caller thread" to be more specific. it takes an effort to share local variable between threads without global or static pointer, except, maybe, when using it in the thread arg, therefore maybe need to add to the answer that changeable thread arg, must be unique and devoted for each thread, in any case it is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fnv1Hash()` doesn't access any non-local state other than the data pointed to by `key`. Assuming the content of the array `key` points to isn't written to concurrently, there is no threading issue. Of course, if another thread writes to the array pointed to by `key`, all bets are off.

Given that `fnv1Hash()` does access any of the object's data it doesn't need a `this` pointer. Thus, it is made `static` to indicate both to the human reader and the compiler that the objects won't be accessed implicitly. For the compiler the upshot is that it doesn't need to pass a `this` pointer.

Comment: thanks , MAy I ask , what is the static for in function fnv1Hash ? I can not see  if fnv1Hash  static or not would make any difference in class StringHashTable .

Comment: A `static` member doesn't get an implicit object passed, i.e., there is no `this` pointer. It is like a non-member function but with access to `private` and `protected` members of the class it is a member of (different question, though, and [one already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13790828/1120273)).